# Any number inserted just appears as 1 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When I enter value to db its only inserting a 1 instead of the whole value entered.

```
$price1=$_POST['proprice'];
$price2=$_POST['proprices'];
if($price2>0){$price=$price2 && $prices=$price1;}else{$price=$price1 && $prices=0;}
$query = "UPDATE products SET pname =:proname,pdesc=:prodesc,pfeat=:profeat,pprice='$price',pprice2='$prices',pcondition='$_POST[pcondition]',pmanu='$_POST[promanu]',plink='$_POST[prolink]'WHERE pid=$post";
```

Comment: What do you expect from statements like `$price=$price2 && $prices=$price1;` or `$price=$price1 && $prices=0;` ?

Comment: Read about SQL injection.

Comment: the value for $price is ok but for $price2 is just 1

Comment: Can we see the schema for the table, perhaps that column is a tinyint(1)?

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
$price=$price2 && $prices=$price1;
```

is evaluated as

```
$price=($price2 && ($prices=$price1));
```

and not as

```
($price=$price2) && ($prices=$price1);
```

Therefore you yield the result of the boolean expression as value for $price.

Substitute the `&&` by `;`, as in

```
if($price2>0){$price=$price2; $prices=$price1;}else{$price=$price1; $prices=0;}
```

Your `&&`-interconnected code would also result in not being executed `$prices=0;` if $price1 is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

`&&` has higher precedence (= is evaluated earlier) than `=`, meaning your expression becomes:

```
$price = (($price2 && $prices) = $price1);
```

when you `&&` two integers, it returns `1` if they are both non-zero. And that value you assign to `$price`.